# If I have two footnotes in one point, and the second footnote begins with a comment, is the first word capitalized? (Turabian)

Tags: chicago-manual-of-style

> Shaw, *The Pharaoh*, pp. 14-15; for examples of exceptions to father-son succession, see Ibid., pp. 8, 37, 41, 59-63.

or

> Shaw, *The Pharaoh*, pp. 14-15; For examples of exceptions to father-son succession, see Ibid., pp. 8, 37, 41, 59-63.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In English, words are not capitalized after a semicolon. And "ibid." needs to be in lowercase, too.

Either:

> Shaw, *The Pharaoh*, pp. 14-15. For examples of exceptions to father-son succession, see ibid., pp. 8, 37, 41, 59-63.

or:

> Shaw, *The Pharaoh*, pp. 14-15; for examples of exceptions to father-son succession, see ibid., pp. 8, 37, 41, 59-63.

---

Just to clarify: That is *one* footnote, not two. Your footnote consists of two sentences.

Footnotes can consist of serveral sentences or even multiple paragraphs, and contain tables and figures, just like your body text.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks I didnt even realize that I was supposed to write “ibid” when its not at the start